# In Makefile: read version from other text file and put the result into a variable in the Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I have an file named "Version.h" with the content of:

```
#define APP_VERSION_MAJOR   5
#define APP_VERSION_MINOR   6
#define APP_VERSION_PATCH   0
```

I have a Makefile, and I want to assign a variable in the Makefile, according to the "Version.h" file, in this case:

```
MY_APP_VERSION = 5.6.0
```

I managed to find the line with the following command:

```
@echo "The result is: $$(grep "#define APP_VERSION_MINOR    " Version.h)"
```

Output:

```
The result is: #define APP_VERSION_MINOR    6
```

So, how can I put the version in a variable in the Makefile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To set a make variable you can do something like this:

```
getnum = $(shell sed -n 's/.*$1  *\([0-9*]\)/\1/p' Version.h)

MY_APP_VERSION := $(call getnum,MAJOR).$(call getnum,MINOR).$(call getnum,PATCH)
```

This does invoke sed 3 times though.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this is your makefile:

```
all:
    @echo The result is: \
    $$(grep '#define APP_VERSION_MAJOR' Version.h | cut -d' ' -f5).\
    $$(grep '#define APP_VERSION_MINOR' Version.h | cut -d' ' -f5).\
    $$(grep '#define APP_VERSION_PATCH' Version.h | cut -d' ' -f5)
```

Then a simple `make` gives you

```
$ make
The result is: 5.6.0
```

Comment: This doesn't put anything in a variable.  Calling `grep | cut` three times screams out for refactoring into an Awk script.

Answer (score 1):

If you manage to read in the file into a variable (my version of make fails to read with `$(file < version.h)`  but yours may work) then you can use [the GNU make table toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt). It was designed exactly for this purpose:

```
include gmtt.mk

tbl := 3 $(strip $(file < version.h)) # make a table with 3 columns from the file

versions := $(strip $(call select,3,$(tbl),t)) # select 3rd column from table, t(rue) as where-clause

MY_APP_VERSION := $(subst $(space),.,$(versions))
```

The file must obey the format that you displayed above so that it can be interpreted as a table with three columns. It has the additional benefit that you don't have to care for which shell (e.g. on Windows) is available.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
APP_VERSION_MAJOR := $(shell awk '// { if ($$2 = 'APP_VERSION_MAJOR) { print $$3 } }' < Version.h)
```

The `:=` inhibits repeated expansion of the shell command, and the `awk` command extracts the the value of the assignment.

With more recent GNU make versions, this should work as well (assuming `Version.h` doesn't use tabs):

```
$(foreach i, \
  $(shell sed 's/#define \([^ ]*\)  *\([^ ]*\)/\1:=\2/' < Version.h), \
  $(eval $i))
```

It has the advantage that it will translate many preprocessor defines in one go, no matter what the specifics are, but it can easily go very wrong if `Version.h` contains unexpected text.